# Examine for convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}$

Now my question is that when I look at the solution, the first step is to write it as

$$\frac{\frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}}{(\frac{2}{3})^n}$$

where did the $(\frac{2}{3})^n$ come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution doesn't change $ \frac{2^n + n^2}{3^n + n^3} $ into something else. It "compares" your sum to $ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) ^n $: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test